# What is this Chr$ function?

Tags: vba, visual-studio

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal Password As String) As String
    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim iTemp As Integer

    Encrypt = " "
    For iIndex = 1 To Len(Password)
        iTemp = Asc(Mid$(Password, iIndex, 1)) * iIndex - iIndex
        Encrypt = Chr$(iTemp Mod 255) & Encrypt
    Next iIndex
End Function
```

This is a function I found in a legacy application. I'm trying to use this function to encrypt the database password column data. When I paste this code into my visual studio the `Chr$` function shows an error, and if I remove the dollar sign ($), it works, but the result is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a backward compatible `CHR()`.

For more info see: http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/VNN529/QC649013521.htm